# "Error detecting buildpack" during Heroku CI Test Setup

Tags: heroku, heroku-ci

All,

Attempting to use Heroku's new-ish Continuous Integration service but it doesn't appear to want to play well with its own framework.

I've setup my Heroku Pipeline as outlined in the CI article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci#configuration-using-app-json. 
 My deployments to review apps work correctly. 
 But my CI tests error with the following

app.json

```
  "buildpacks": [
    { "url": "heroku/jvm" },
    { "url": "heroku/nodejs" }
  ],
```

Results in

```
$ heroku ci:debug --pipeline mypipelinename
Preparing source... done
Creating test run... done
Running setup and attaching to test dyno...
~ $ ci setup && eval $(ci env)
-----> Fetching heroku/jvm buildpack...
       error downloading buildpack
```

I'm using the JVM buildpack so that I may install liquibase which manages version control for my Postgresql DB, but I'm actually deploying a NodeJs app.

Why would my "Review App"s deploy without problems but die during "Test Setup"?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get past this by using the github url for the node buildpack

```
"buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs"
    }
],
```

I imagine it will work the same for jvm